# Multiple conditions for joined the table's column in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, join, sqlalchemy

I have two models:

```
class Room(Base, SerializerMixin):
      __tablename__ = "rooms"

      id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
      last_updated = Column(Integer)
      participants = relationship("RoomParticipant")

      def __init__(self, p_id, last_updated):
          self.id = p_id
          self.last_updated = last_updated

class RoomParticipant(Base, SerializerMixin):
      __tablename__ = "room_participants"

      id = Column(String, primary_key=True)
      room_id = Column(String, ForeignKey("rooms.id"))
      user_id = Column(String, ForeignKey("users.id"))
      user = relationship("User", load_on_pending=True)

      def __init__(self, p_id, room_id, user_id):
          self.id = p_id
          self.room_id = room_id
          self.user_id = user_id
```

For example: I have one row in the `rooms` table with `id=3`. And I have two rows in the `room_participants` table: the first one with `id=1` and the second one with `id=2`. And the `room_id` column of the each row in the room_participants table equals to `3`. I know this two `id`s. And now I need to do something like: "give me a row from the `rooms` table, which have the row with `id=1` and the row with `id=2` from the `room_participants` table as a relationship".

What should the SQLAlchemy query look like? And is it even possible?
Thanks in advance)

Answer (score 1):

After 5 days I just found a solution. The `in_` function helped.

```
@classmethod
def get(cls, user1_id, user2_id) -> Room:
    return DBSession.query(Room) \
        .join(RoomParticipant, DM.id == RoomParticipant.dm_id, isouter=True) \
        .filter(RoomParticipant.user_id.in_((user1_id, user2_id))) \
        .group_by(Room.id) \
        .having(func.count(distinct(RoomParticipant.user_id)) == 2) \
        .first()
```